# Select an item from the WebDriver drop-down list

Tags: selenium-webdriver

You need to select a specific item in the drop-down list. At this stage, the difficulty is that the list does not respond when clicked.

WebDriver, Selenium 3.141.59, Google Chrome

Website https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator
In the Operating System item, I need to choose "Free....."driver.switchTo().frame(0);

```
driver.switchTo().frame("myFrame");

WebElement operatingSystem = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//md-select-value/span/div[contains(text(),'Free')]/../../..")));
operatingSystem.click();
WebElement checkFree = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//md-option/div[contains(text(),'Free')]/..")));
checkFree.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select fruits = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("subjects")));
    fruits.selectByVisibleText("maths");
    fruits.selectByIndex(1);
```

The above code must run fine in case of dropdowns.